# Can WCF Service Return Zip stream?

Tags: c#, wcf, dotnetzip

I had to store some very big strings in an XML file. Now I wanted to compress the strings using a `GZipStream` and then decompress them later at client side.
**Can WCF Service Method return zip stream as return type?**

There is my service method:

```
public Stream ZipResponse()
{
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    GZipStream compressionStream = null;
    try
    {
        var var_details = "XML String Here";
        byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(var_details);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        compressionStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { }
    return compressionStream;
}
```

Now when i call `ZipResponse()` method from client side it throws:
**An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.  This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.**

Comment: Your question is really vague. Maybe try fleshing it out a bit, show what you've tried and where you got stuck.
Basic answer to your question is yes.
If you need more detail than that, we'll need you to put more detail in the question.

Comment: Sorry Haem for my question..  I have xml string of 12MB at WCF service which i have to return in zip stream to clinet ?

Comment: You can send anything via WCF using binary stream

Comment: My Code is: -public Stream ZipResponse() { byte[] byteArray = null; MemoryStream stream = null; try { var var_details = "XML String"; byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(var_details); stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray); } catch (Exception e) { } return stream; } I am able to return stream from service but i have to return zipstream? –

Comment: @Sam are you having a specific problem with the code? Or is your question just "can it be done?"

Comment: Try catching/logging out exceptions thrown on the server. This exception you are seeing likely means an exception was already thrown in your server code.

Comment: Any final solution with full source code sample about it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a WCF service method can return a Stream to the client.
You should make sure that your transfer mode is set to "streamed"; apart from that, it should be straightforward.

You can get some further info here: [WCF Streaming Tutorial](http://wcftutorial.net/Streaming.aspx)

Comment: Any final solution with full source code sample about it? for 2 cases: a) return Stream to the client (from the service). b) send Stream to the service (from the client)

Comment: @Kiquenet did you try looking at the tutorial I linked?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look this acrticle about 7Zip(LZMA) WCF message compression http://geekswithblogs.net/argot/archive/2009/10/27/wcf-message-compression---gzip-7zip.aspx